# Serve multiple Angular apps from the same server with Nginx

Tags: angular, nginx, routes

I'm serving multiple `angular` apps from the same `server` block in `Nginx`. So in order to let the user browse directly to certain custom `Angular` routes I've declared without having to go through the home page (and avoid the 404 page), I'm forwarding these routes from nginx to each angular app's `index.html`, I've added a `try_files` to each `location`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name website.com;

    # project1
    location / {
        alias /home/hakim/project1/dist/;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    # project2
    location /project2/ {
        alias /home/hakim/project2/dist/;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    # project3
    location /project3/ {
        alias /home/hakim/project3/dist/;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
}
```

This solution avoids the 404 error when going to an Angular route, but the problem is that when I browse to `/project2/` or `/project3/` it redirects to the `/project1/`. That's obviously not what is expected, since I want to have each location to forward to the `/project-i/index.html` of the adequate project.

Comment: You click on a link to project2 from inside project1. and that doesn't work, correct?

Comment: Exactly, but even if I browse directly to `website/project2`, it goes to `project1`.

Comment: You need to use base href maybe

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is generally a bad security practice to have multiple independent apps on a single domain.

However, I believe what you're facing here is the peculiarity of the way that `try_files` works -- according to http://nginx.org/r/try_files,

> If none of the files were found, an internal redirect to the uri specified in the last parameter is made.

Effectively, this means that if there would have been an extra parameter after your `/index.html` specification (i.e., basically, anything at all), then your code would have worked as you expected; however, due to the lack of any such final parameter, what happens in each case is that everything gets redirected back to the `/` `location`, as if a `GET /index.html HTTP/1.1` request was to have been made (except it's all done internally within nginx).

So, as a solution, you can either fix the path for the internal redirect to remain within the same `location` (e.g., `/projectX/index.html`), or leave the paths alone, but make the last parameter return an error code (e.g., `=404`, which should never be triggered as long as your file always exists).

- E.g, `try_files $uri /projectX/index.html;`,
- Or, `try_files $uri /index.html =404;`.

As in:

```
location /projectX/ {
    alias /home/projectX/dist/;
    try_files $uri /projectX/index.html; # last param is internal redirect
}
```

Or:

```
location /projectX/ {
    alias /home/projectX/dist/;
    try_files $uri /index.html =404;
}
```

In summary, note well that `/projectX/index.html` would only work as the last parameter, and `/index.html` would only work as a non-final one.

Comment: You answer was the closest to how I've solved it. I've actually left the `location` for `project1` as it was, while in the try_files in `project2` and `project3` I had to add in their `try_files`'s index.html, the prefix `project-i`. So it became as the following for `project2` and `project3`: `try_files $uri /project[2-3]/index.html`

Comment: @h4k1m, great that it works!  Regarding "the closest", TBH, I don't see how your solution is any different from what I wrote above. :-p  (The other answers are obviously totally wrong -- I never suggested (nor meant to imply) doing any changes for project1.)

Comment: Could you please just mention that the modifications done on location /projectX/, should only be carried out on project2 and project3 (that's what I meant by closest, because when I read it I thought I had to change even the location of the first project).

Comment: @h4k1m, that would only be the case if you just look at the code snippets, and skip the explanation on how it works. :-)

Comment: Curious to know the security issue involved with multiple files in the same domain. Can you kindly explain?

Comment: @Nobody it has to do with Cookies, JavaScript and XSS (Cross-Site Scripting) attacks.  If you use a single domain, the browser treats all apps as the same app, so, vulnerability in one app, makes all the rest of them vulnerable just as much.

Answer (score 17):

Hope this helps someone

**Step 1** - Build all your projects

```
ng build --prod --base-href /project1/
ng build --prod --base-href /project2/
ng build --prod --base-href /project3/
```

**Step 2** - Configure your nginx, note the change added in `try_files` section

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name website.com;

    # project1
    location / {
        alias /home/hakim/project1/dist/;
        try_files $uri/ /project1/index.html;
    }

    # project2
    location /project2/ {
        alias /home/hakim/project2/dist/;
        try_files $uri/ /project2/index.html;
    }

    # project3
    location /project3/ {
        alias /home/hakim/project3/dist/;
        try_files $uri/ /project3/index.html;
    }
}
```

**Step 3** - Reload nginx configuration

```
sudo service nginx reload
```

Comment: can you share a link on this?

Comment: you saved my day

Answer (score 1):

Try building you apps using --base.href=/projectx/ for example:

```
ng build --base.href=/project1/
ng build --base.href=/project2/
ng build --base.href=/project3/
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the solution for [multilingual Angular application AOT builds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50877984/776546) that are basically different apps - OK its the same app multiple times, build with different languages in different bundles in different directories.

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me:

```
server {
    listen port_number;
    server_name ip_addreess_or_domain;

    location project-1 { // without forward slash the last of the location name
       alias /var/www/project-1/;
       try_files $uri $uri/ /project-1/index.html;
    }

    location project-2 { // without forward slash the last of the location name
       alias /var/www/project-2/;
       try_files $uri $uri/ /project-2/index.html;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding to project 2:

```
<base href="/project2">
```

Comment: I've changed `href="/"` to `href="/project2"` in project2/dist/index.html, but it doesn't seem to fix it.

Comment: Did anything change when you added that?

Comment: The behaviour is exactly the same (redirect to /project1).

Answer (score 0):

Change the first location to:

```
# project1
location /project1/ {
    alias /home/hakim/project1/dist/;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
}
```

The current block matches all '/' and it's the first thing that matches the request.