# How to serve an angular app based on the URL using nginx?

Tags: angularjs, nginx, routes

I was wondering how to serve an angular app based on the url while using nginx. So let's say there is a url called xyz.com/something/ and whenever there's something in the url, I want ngnix to route to an angular app. How do we acheive it, I saw similar questions here on SO [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48126517/serve-multiple-angular-apps-from-the-same-server-with-nginx) but just couldn't get it working.

```
location /something/ {
    root /var/www/xyz.com/html/something/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }
```

let's say normally the app would respond to urls like,
`xyz.com/something/login`

The below code is working fine though.

```
location / {
  alias /var/www/xyz.com/html/something/;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
}
```

Have tried something with base-href too as [described here](https://medium.com/@CristianSitov/delivering-multiple-angular2-apps-with-a-single-nginx-server-at-different-urls-55b42ca4c4ce) and yet failed to get it working.

Tried the first answer as well.

**Nginx CONFIG file:**

```
location /admin {
    root /var/www/xyz.com/html/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /admin/index.html;
}

location / {
    alias /var/www/xyz.com/html/user/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
}
```

Here /admin & /user refers to two different AngularJs projects present on same domain.

**TEST CASES:**

```
URL : www.xyz.com/admin/
RESPONSE : Blank page.. 
           accessing index.html but not redirecting properly

URL : www.xyz.com/admin/login
RESPONSE : Blank page..
  ERRORS : Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'login'
```

but I have routed properly..

Any Suggestions??

Comment: Is it finding `index.html` but not your resource files?

Comment: Yes, exactly that's what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You have too many "something"s. The path to the file is constructed by appending the URI to the value of `root`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) for details.

In your configuration, the file terms `$uri` and `$uri/` will not match andy files.

If you remove the `something` from your `root` value, you will need to add it to the `index.html` file element.

For example:

```
location /something/ {
    root /var/www/xyz.com/html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /something/index.html;
}
```

Personally, I do not append the `=404`, but it does no harm, and I know that many Angular tutorials seem to think it's necessary. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

Comment: Hey, tried your suggestion as well. Have updated the results from it on the question above. Kindly have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

```
location /angular/ {
    root   /opt/app-root/src;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /angular/index.html;
}
```

```
COPY dist/angular-app/. /opt/app-root/src/angular
```